# how to read a .js file into a DataFrame

Tags: dataframe, file-io, julia

i have the following non standard file and want to read it efficiently into a Dataframe, but do not know how to efficiently handle it.

```
m[mi++]="18.06.16 22:00:00|0;3;1;1667;49;49;12|0;17;3;2153;328;153;57|0;18;0;2165;284;156;53"
m[mi++]="18.06.16 21:55:00|0;24;7;1667;306;306;61|0;21;4;2153;384;166;62|0;19;1;2165;368;185;62"
m[mi++]="18.06.16 21:50:00|0;31;6;1667;394;349;62|0;32;6;2153;402;164;63|0;33;4;2165;380;171;63"
m[mi++]="18.06.16 21:45:00|11;50;19;1667;390;312;63|34;61;9;2153;410;166;63|19;60;8;2165;391;185;63"
m[mi++]="18.06.16 21:40:00|37;63;24;1666;387;313;63|55;80;12;2150;418;169;64|46;79;11;2163;398;186;63"
```

If I have saved this data in a file a.js the following code works:

```
b = readtable("a.js")
dat_5m = DataFrame(t=DateTime[], Pac_1=Float64[], Pdc_A1=Float64[], Pdc_B1=Float64[], Etot1=Float64[],
    U_A1=Float64[], U_B1=Float64[], T_1=Float64[], Pac_2=Float64[], Pdc_A2=Float64[], Pdc_B2=Float64[],
    Etot2=Float64[], U_A2=Float64[], U_B2=Float64[], T_2=Float64[], Pac_3=Float64[], Pdc_A3=Float64[],
    Pdc_B3=Float64[], Etot3=Float64[], U_A3=Float64[], U_B3=Float64[], T_3=Float64[])
for r in nrow(b):-1:1
   c = split(b[r,1], [';','|','=']);
   d = float(c[3:end])'
   t = DateTime(c[2], DateFormat("dd.mm.yy HH:MM:SS"))
   push!(dat_5m, [t d])
end
```

But I think it is quite unelegant. Is there any more efficient way?

Comment: Why not just replace `|` with `;` and get rid of the beginning bit to get a consistent delimiter? Then you can just use `CSV.jl` to read it. I have some simple tutorials on my blog on how to use that package: http://www.beeandkey.com/2018/03/reading-csv-files-part-i.html

Comment: I also think preprocessing the input data is the way to go.

Comment: Ok. I followed your hints, but it does not really work out for me:
`b = readstring(a[2]);
b = replace(b, "|", ";");
b = replace(b, "m[mi++]=\"", "");
CSV.read(b; delim=";")` Any further hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If possible (IO permitting), I'd recommend cleaning the file first, removing `|` and any funky `"` and prefixes. Then you can use `CSV.jl` to make your life easier.

The process is: read line by line, clean each line and then use `CSV` to read it back in:

```
julia> using CSV

julia> open("b.js", "a") do new_file
           for line in readlines("a.js")
               line = replace(line, "m[mi++]=\"", "")
               # remove only trailing quote
               line = replace(line, r"\"$", "")
               line = replace(line, "|", ";")
               write(new_file, string(line, "\n"))
           end
       end


julia> b = CSV.read("b.js",
           delim = ";",
           header = false, # change this to a string vector to provide column names
           dateformat = "dd.mm.yy HH:MM:SS");

julia> # correct times to be in 2016
       b[:Column1] += Dates.Year(2000);

julia> head(b)
6×22 DataFrames.DataFrame. Omitted printing of 15 columns
│ Row │ Column1             │ Column2 │ Column3 │ Column4 │ Column5 │ Column6 │ Column7 │
├─────┼─────────────────────┼─────────┼─────────┼─────────┼─────────┼─────────┼─────────┤
│ 1   │ 2016-06-18T22:00:00 │ 0       │ 3       │ 1       │ 1667    │ 49      │ 49      │
│ 2   │ 2016-06-18T21:55:00 │ 0       │ 24      │ 7       │ 1667    │ 306     │ 306     │
│ 3   │ 2016-06-18T21:50:00 │ 0       │ 31      │ 6       │ 1667    │ 394     │ 349     │
│ 4   │ 2016-06-18T21:45:00 │ 11      │ 50      │ 19      │ 1667    │ 390     │ 312     │
│ 5   │ 2016-06-18T21:40:00 │ 37      │ 63      │ 24      │ 1666    │ 387     │ 313     │
│ 6   │ 2016-06-18T22:00:00 │ 0       │ 3       │ 1       │ 1667    │ 49      │ 49      │
```

I cleaned the lines here step by step to make the process easier to understand. If you're a regex master you might want to do that in one line.

There might be a better way of handling the 2 digit years, so if someone knows how to fix that please edit this answer or add it as a comment. Thanks!

Edit:
If you want to do the same without writing to another file, here's a hack to apply the cleaning function, and reuse `CSV.read()` by converting the `readlines` array to a `IOBuffer` again:

```
function cleaner(line)
    line = replace(line, "m[mi++]=\"", "")
    line = replace(line, r"\"$", "")
    line = replace(line, "|", ";")
    println(line)
    string(line, "\n")
end

c = CSV.read(
    Base.IOBuffer(
        string(cleaner.(readlines("a.js"))...)),
        delim = ";",
        header = false,
        dateformat = "dd.mm.yy HH:MM:SS");

c[:Column1] += Dates.Year(2000);
```

This gives the same result as the other solution.

Comment: thanks. It is not possible to just create a kind of temporary file, where the data is stored and then directly read from? I really have to save it again on disk?

Comment: you don't have to, but this is the easiest way. Is this file too big for such a manoeuvre?

Comment: no, its possible, but there is for every day such a file ... Like a few thousand already. Ok, I could always overwrite the same file, but I thought a different way might be more elegant ....

Comment: Edited my answer with a new solution that doesn't require you to write new files. Might be less efficient, though. I'm not sure.